# Why when I try to return the movie the code returns as empty/null?

Tags: kotlin

```
 data class AvailableMovies (val name: String, val year: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
      return "Nome: $name, Ano: $year"

    }
}
data class MovieInfo(var rented: Boolean = false, var rentedBy: String = "", var price: Double = 0.0) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Preço: R$%.2f.".format(price)
    }
}  



println("type the CPF of the client:")
    val clientCPF = scanner.nextLine()

    val customerMovies = filmAvailability.filter { it.rentedBy == clientCPF}
    val clientFound = clients.find { it.cpf == clientCPF }

    if (clientFound == null) {
        println("Cliente com CPF '$clientCPF' não encontrado.")
        return
    }

    println("Filmes alugados pelo cliente '${clientFound.name}':")
    customerMovies.forEachIndexed { index, movie ->
        val rentedMovie = movies.find { it.name == movie.rentedBy }
        if(rentedMovie != null) {
            println("${index + 1} - ${rentedMovie.name} - Ano: ${rentedMovie.year}")
        } else {
            println("nothing here")
        }
    }
```

I'm starting in programming, I've been at this for 2 days and I can't make it work

Comment: Without knowing further details about your data model, but `it.name == movie.rentedBy` seems strange. Ie `it.name` seems to be the name of a movie but `movie.rentedby` seems to be the name of a customer/person. How would they ever be equal?